# pgfplots: group stacked bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create groups of 5 stacked xbars, using `y expr={\thisrow{y} - (mod(\thisrow{y},5)/2)}`. However, after some groups, the calculation seems to get thrown off and the third group actually consists of 6 bars:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{%
x y
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
11 11
12 12
13 13
14 14
15 15
16 16
17 17
18 18
19 19
20 20
21 21
}\loadedtable

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xbar stacked, ytick=data, y=0.9cm]
                \addplot table[x=x,y expr={\thisrow{y} - (mod(\thisrow{y},5)/2)}] \loadedtable ;
                \addplot table[x=x,y expr={\thisrow{y} - (mod(\thisrow{y},5)/2)}] \loadedtable ;
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jubobs Got it. That's precision problem it will repeat itself at 30,40,55 etc. because `Mod` is not in there yet and `mod` uses truncation

Comment: @percusse Glad you figured it out. I was worried I was simply missing something really obvious. Do you mind elaborating in a full-blow answer?

Comment: @percusse On second thought, I think the problem lies with `\thisrow`, not with `mod`. Try `\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{15-0.5*mod(15,5)}
     \draw node {\myresult};` inside a `tikzpicture` and you get 15, as expected.

Comment: @percusse `\foreach[count=\xi] \x in {15,30,40,55}
     {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{\x-0.5*mod(\x,5)}
      \draw (\xi,0) node {\myresult};
   }` produces fine results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of numerical inaccuracies of the `mod` function when using the `fpu` library (which is the case for most calculations within an `axis` environment). Sometimes, the function incorrectly returns the divisor instead of zero (`\pgfmathparse{mod(15,5)}`, for instance).

You can fix this by defining a new version of the `mod` function that checks for this error:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fpumod}{2}{%
    \pgfmathfloatdivide{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatint{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathfloatmultiply{\pgfmathresult}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatsubtract{#1}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathfloatifapproxequalrel{\pgfmathresult}{#2}{\def\pgfmathresult{0}}{}%
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fpumod}{2}{%
    \pgfmathfloatdivide{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatint{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathfloatmultiply{\pgfmathresult}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatsubtract{#1}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathfloatifapproxequalrel{\pgfmathresult}{#2}{\def\pgfmathresult{0}}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{%
x y
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
11 11
12 12
13 13
14 14
15 15
16 16
17 17
18 18
19 19
20 20
21 21
}\loadedtable

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xbar stacked, ytick=data, y=0.9cm]
                \addplot table[x=x,y expr={\thisrow{y} - (fpumod(\thisrow{y},5)/2)}] \loadedtable ;
                \addplot table[x=x,y expr={\thisrow{y} - (fpumod(\thisrow{y},5)/2)}] \loadedtable ;
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Sherlock Holmes :) But who is the culprit? `fpu` or the implementation of `mod`? Is the `fpu` not compliant with the IEEE-754 standard?