# some of the boxplots in a group shifted

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxplot

Some of the box plots are shifted. Can you please help me to solve it?

(code is copied from user [Korijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/45341/korijn)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    ylabel={AAAAA},
    height=6cm,
    ymin=0,ymax=7,
    cycle list={{red},{black}},
    boxplot={
        %
        % Idea: 
        %  place the 
        %  group 1 at 0.3333 and 0.6666
        %  group 2 at 1.3333 and 1.6666
        %  group 3 at 2.3333 and 2.6666
        %  ...
        % in a formular:
        draw position={1/3 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/2) + 1/3*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,2)},
        %
        % that means the box extend must be at most 0.33333 :
        box extend=0.2
    },
    % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
    x=1cm,
    % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
    xtick={0,1,2,...,20},
    x tick label as interval,
    xticklabels={%
        {0.15},%
        {0.2},%
        {0.25},%
        {0.3},%
        {0.4},%
        {0.5},%
        {0.6},%
        {0.8},%
        {1.0},
    },
    x tick label style={
        text width=2.5cm,
        align=center
    },
    ]
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.764\\
        2.938\\
        2.075\\
        1.493\\
        1.285\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.175\\
        2.813\\
        2.006\\
        3.893\\
        2.012\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.621\\
        3.659\\
        6.357\\
        2.851\\
        1.416\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.280\\
        1.482\\
        1.787\\
        2.326\\
        1.795\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.778\\
        2.388\\
        1.016\\
        1.328\\
        1.151\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.028\\
        1.571\\
        4.090\\
        3.875\\
        1.890\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };
    %----------------------%
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.778\\
        2.388\\
        1.016\\
        1.328\\
        1.151\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.028\\
        1.571\\
        4.090\\
        3.875\\
        1.890\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };

%------------------------------%

        \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };
    %----------------------%
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.778\\
        2.388\\
        1.016\\
        1.328\\
        1.151\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.028\\
        1.571\\
        4.090\\
        3.875\\
        1.890\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };


    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit by ManuelKuehner

*Code based on [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183778) ans menioned in the comments.*

Comment: I can't compile your code please edit your question. Do you need alway groups with 2 boxes, pairs?

Comment: yes I always need 2 boxes.

Comment: Can you check it please? I edited it.

Comment: I tried, but at the moment i can't solve it. I thing the problem is `draw position={1/3 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/2) + 1/3*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,2)},`.  I don't know `\plotnumofactualtype`. Your addplot data do not tangent the problem. Your code is from [Christian Feuersänger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183856/124842) (please ref.)

Comment: Code from other should be attributed as mentioned above. Also, do you no longer need your earlier question? These seem to be grouped. If so, please delete that one so people don't spend time on it. Or can it be closed as a duplicate of another question you found later?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Looks helpful, but what do you mean by 'do not tangent the problem'?

Comment: @cfr ups...nothing. Wrong place for this, if i could i would edit the comment. It refers to an other question. Copy and paste failed here. Sorry. Do you know something about `\plotnumofactualtype`?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Sorry, no - no clue at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution from this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363830/multiple-boxplots/363833). I adapted it to my code. It seems the problem is because of a bug in mod function. The problem is solved in

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fpumod}{2}{%
    \pgfmathfloatdivide{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatint{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathfloatmultiply{\pgfmathresult}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatsubtract{#1}{\pgfmathresult}%
    % replaced `0' by `5' to make it work for this problem
    \pgfmathfloatifapproxequalrel{\pgfmathresult}{#2}{\def\pgfmathresult{3}}{}%
}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    boxplot/draw direction=y,
    ylabel={AAAAA},
    height=6cm,
    ymin=0,ymax=7,
    cycle list={{red},{black}},
    boxplot={
        draw position={1/3 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/2) + 1/3*fpumod(\plotnumofactualtype,2)},
        box extend=0.15
    },
    % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
    x=1cm,
    % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
    xtick={0,1,2,...,20},
    x tick label as interval,
    xticklabels={%
        {0.15},%
        {0.2},%
        {0.25},%
        {0.3},%
        {0.4},%
        {0.5},%
        {0.6},%
        {0.8},%
        {1.0},
    },
    x tick label style={
        text width=2.5cm,
        align=center
    },
    ]
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.764\\
        2.938\\
        2.075\\
        1.493\\
        1.285\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.175\\
        2.813\\
        2.006\\
        3.893\\
        2.012\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.621\\
        3.659\\
        4.357\\
        2.851\\
        1.416\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.280\\
        1.482\\
        1.787\\
        2.326\\
        1.795\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.778\\
        2.388\\
        1.016\\
        1.328\\
        1.151\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.028\\
        1.571\\
        4.090\\
        3.875\\
        1.890\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };
    %----------------------%
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.778\\
        2.388\\
        1.016\\
        1.328\\
        1.151\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.028\\
        1.571\\
        4.090\\
        3.875\\
        1.890\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };

%------------------------------%

        \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };
    %----------------------%
    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.778\\
        2.388\\
        1.016\\
        1.328\\
        1.151\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.028\\
        1.571\\
        4.090\\
        3.875\\
        1.890\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        1.405\\
        1.188\\
        4.330\\
        3.665\\
        1.439\\
    };

    \addplot
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        2.937\\
        1.320\\
        1.357\\
        1.852\\
        1.215\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The post that I gave mention this problem as 'a well known bug of mod function'.