# Problem in adding legend and space in a tikzpicture plot in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have tried different ways to put colour legend for this chart but failed or not aligned. Can you please advise.

So `\legend{}` did not provide anything and `\addlegendry{}` is not alleged. I just want a simple legend to name each colour as type A,B,C,D,E.

Also, it is possible to add extra space between the region's box charts?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
    % borrowed from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145967/95441>
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{fpumod}{2}{%
        \pgfmathfloatdivide{#1}{#2}%
        \pgfmathfloatint{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfmathfloatmultiply{\pgfmathresult}{#2}%
        \pgfmathfloatsubtract{#1}{\pgfmathresult}%
        % replaced `0' by `5' to make it work for this problem
        \pgfmathfloatifapproxequalrel{\pgfmathresult}{#2}{\def\pgfmathresult{5}}{}%
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     legend entries = {A, B,C,D,E},
  legend to name={legend},
 % name=border,
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        ylabel={time (s)},
        height=8cm,
        boxplot={
            % in a formular:
            draw position={
                1/10+ floor(\plotnumofactualtype/5)
                + 1/5*fpumod(\plotnumofactualtype,5)
            },
            % that means the box extend must be at most 0.2 :
            box extend=0.15,
        },
        % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
        x=3cm,
        % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
        xtick={0,1,2,...,50},
%        x tick label as interval,
    xticklabels={%
          {Region 1},%
          {Region 2},%
          {Region 3},%
          {Region 4},%     
        },
        x tick label style={
          text width=2.5cm,
          align=right,
          xshift=6ex
        },
        cycle list={{green},{cyan},{blue},{orange},{red}},
      legend pos=north west
    ]
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            6\\
            51\\
            71\\
            50\\
            125\\
        };\legend{A}

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            8\\
            69\\
            90\\
            70\\
            153\\
        };

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            75\\
            41\\
            30\\
            88\\
            29\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            56\\
            80\\
            356\\
            20\\
            36\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            68\\
            34\\
            70\\
            32\\
            37\\
        };

    % block 2
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
         \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };

    % block 3
          \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };

    % block 4
           \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! I am not sure if I am on the right track. AFAIK there is no real predefined legend for pure box plots, but I may be wrong. (Let me note that if you switch to a more recent version, e.g. `compat=1.16`, the output changes quite a bit in that it shows also samples.) Anyway, this adds a possible `legend image code` for such a legend.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
% borrowed from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145967/95441>
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fpumod}{2}{%
    \pgfmathfloatdivide{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatint{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathfloatmultiply{\pgfmathresult}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatsubtract{#1}{\pgfmathresult}%
    % replaced `0' by `5' to make it work for this problem
    \pgfmathfloatifapproxequalrel{\pgfmathresult}{#2}{\def\pgfmathresult{5}}{}%
}
\pgfplotsset{boxplot legend/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
        \draw[#1] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.3cm)
        (0.3cm,0cm) -- (0.3cm,-0.1cm) (0.1cm,-0.1cm) -- (0.5cm,-0.1cm)
        (0.3cm,0.3cm) -- (0.3cm,0.4cm) (0.1cm,0.4cm) -- (0.5cm,0.4cm);
    },
}}
\newcounter{iloop}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend entries = {A, B,C,D,E},
%   legend to name={legend},
 % name=border,
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        ylabel={time (s)},
        height=8cm,width=12cm,
        boxplot={
            % in a formular:
            draw position={
                1/10+ floor(\plotnumofactualtype/5)
                + 1/5*fpumod(\plotnumofactualtype,5)
            },
            % that means the box extend must be at most 0.2 :
            box extend=0.15,
        },
        % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
        %x=3cm,
        % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
        xtick={0,1,2,...,50},
%        x tick label as interval,
    xticklabels={%
          {Region 1},%
          {Region 2},%
          {Region 3},%
          {Region 4},%     
        },
        x tick label style={
          text width=2.5cm,
          align=right,
          xshift=6ex
        },
        cycle list={{green},{cyan},{blue},{orange},{red}},
        legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)},anchor=north west},
    ]
        \setcounter{iloop}{0}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{{green},{cyan},{blue},{orange},{red}}
        {\addlegendimage{boxplot legend=#1}
        \stepcounter{iloop}
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\addlegendentry[#1]{\Alph{iloop}}}
        \temp}

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            6\\
            51\\
            71\\
            50\\
            125\\
        };
        %\addlegendentry{A}

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            8\\
            69\\
            90\\
            70\\
            153\\
        };

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            75\\
            41\\
            30\\
            88\\
            29\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            56\\
            80\\
            356\\
            20\\
            36\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            68\\
            34\\
            70\\
            32\\
            37\\
        };

    % block 2
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
         \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };

    % block 3
          \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };

    % block 4
           \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a version that supports arbitrary texts.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
% borrowed from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145967/95441>
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fpumod}{2}{%
    \pgfmathfloatdivide{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatint{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathfloatmultiply{\pgfmathresult}{#2}%
    \pgfmathfloatsubtract{#1}{\pgfmathresult}%
    % replaced `0' by `5' to make it work for this problem
    \pgfmathfloatifapproxequalrel{\pgfmathresult}{#2}{\def\pgfmathresult{5}}{}%
}
\pgfplotsset{boxplot legend/.style={
    legend image code/.code={
        \draw[#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.4cm,0.1cm)
        (0.2cm,-0.1cm) -- (0.2cm,-0.2cm) (0.05cm,-0.2cm) -- (0.35cm,-0.2cm)
        (0.2cm,0.1cm) -- (0.2cm,0.2cm) (0.05cm,0.2cm) -- (0.35cm,0.2cm);
     \path (0cm,0.24cm) (0cm,-0.24cm);  
    },
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      legend entries = {A, B,C,D,E},
%   legend to name={legend},
 % name=border,
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        ylabel={time (s)},
        height=8cm,width=12cm,
        boxplot={
            % in a formular:
            draw position={
                1/10+ floor(\plotnumofactualtype/5)
                + 1/5*fpumod(\plotnumofactualtype,5)
            },
            % that means the box extend must be at most 0.2 :
            box extend=0.15,
        },
        % ... it also means that 1 unit in x controls the width:
        %x=3cm,
        % ... and it means that we should describe intervals:
        xtick={0,1,2,...,50},
%        x tick label as interval,
    xticklabels={%
          {Region 1},%
          {Region 2},%
          {Region 3},%
          {Region 4},%     
        },
        x tick label style={
          text width=2.5cm,
          align=right,
          xshift=6ex
        },
        cycle list={{green},{cyan},{blue},{orange},{red}},
        legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)},anchor=north west},
    ]
        \setcounter{iloop}{0}
        \foreach \Color/\Text in {green/smth,cyan/purr,blue/pft,orange/hibernate,red/honey}
        {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addlegendimage{boxplot legend=\Color}
        \noexpand\addlegendentry[\Color]{\Text}}
        \temp}

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            6\\
            51\\
            71\\
            50\\
            125\\
        };
        %\addlegendentry{A}

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            8\\
            69\\
            90\\
            70\\
            153\\
        };

        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            75\\
            41\\
            30\\
            88\\
            29\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            56\\
            80\\
            356\\
            20\\
            36\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            68\\
            34\\
            70\\
            32\\
            37\\
        };

    % block 2
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
         \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };

    % block 3
          \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };

    % block 4
           \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            60\\
            516\\
            710\\
            503\\
            1253\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            759\\
            419\\
            309\\
            883\\
            299\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            516\\
            480\\
            1356\\
            200\\
            736\\
        };
        \addplot table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            684\\
            340\\
            700\\
            325\\
            377\\
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thnks! It does not show when I change the A,B ,,, names in the legend.

Comment: I meant i want to insert different names instead of A, B,C, D and E. It would be great to make the size smaller as well.

Comment: @Jackson I added a version with smaller symbols that supports arbitrary texts.

Comment: Thank you!. Highly appreciated.